# Format "duration" via script in Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, format

Is it possible to format a GS cell via a script? Datas from my script are duration, but when I copy them in GS, when the value is less than 24:00 GS considers them as date, and when the value is more than 24:00 GS considers them as duration.

I can manually format the cell with duration in GS, but there is a loooot of cells, so I'd like to do it with a script.

Is it possible?

Thanks,

Adblayrog

Comment: Check the Range Class there are several ways to change format including setNumberFormat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **setNumberFormat()** function.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
ss.getRange('A1:A10').setNumberFormat('[hh]:mm:ss');
```

[Reference](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/formats)

But if your durations are in a column or a row, you can select them all and format as duration without any need to a script.

Comment: Thanks for your response.
I tried with .setNumberformat(), but the problem is still there : if the duration is less than 24:00, GS identifies the value like a date instead of a duration.
I know I can manually format a range directly with GS, but each day I have ten new files created, and I do not want to do it manually. So I'd like a solution with a script to format a range like a duration.

Comment: Sorry, it was my mistake.  I wrote without the square brackets... But now, with the brackets, I have a new problem. Ex : for 2 hours and 10 minutes, it is written "02:130:7800". So for each unit, it converts the total duration. But thanks, your response was good. I will look for the source of my new problem.

Comment: Just like you said, it converts total duration for each unit freakishly. When I tried with "[hh]:ss.mm" it worked. :)